# Scanner, stream и ооп

Tags: java, ооп, потоки-данных

Есть класс `TestClass`.  Если это важно, тесты на junit. Но сама тестовая логика в процессе написания.
В этом классе создается сканер

```
void getBusinessCard () {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        BusinessCardImpl b=new BusinessCardImpl ();
        b.getBusinessCard (scanner);

    }
```

Вот сам метод.

```
public BusinessCard getBusinessCard (Scanner scanner) {
    String rawInput = scanner.next ();
    return this;
}
```

И ничего не происходит. Программа висит, ввод невозможен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не вырывайте "фразы" из контекста, выкладывайте весь код. То что вы скинули должно работать без проблем. Висит в каком смысле? она должна висеть, т.к. ожидает ввод текста, т.к. вызван метод nextLine

Comment: Переписал, добавил конкретики

Comment: @Vladimir ищите есть ли где то в коде у вас scanner.nextInt

Comment: есть гит с вашим проектом?

Comment: @Санаев , на проект не тянет, это единственные рализованные методы.

Comment: @Vladimir в конструкторе что? Попробуйте исправить на scanner.nextLine()

Comment: @Санаев по умолчанию

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76287/discussion-between--and-vladimir).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Junit** **тесты** не предназначены для ручного ввода. Они созданы для автоматического тестирования!

Comment: если мой ответ не понятен, пишите , отвечу на вопросы.